# indexed varchar column can not be used when query condition is now() function in mysql

Tags: mysql

**Background:**

In my case, mysql is 5.7.

There is a table named `A` and a indexed column named `date_str`. Data in `date_str` looks like `2017-01-16 00:00:00`.

**Problem:**

I've found out that the index can not be used in a range query such as `select * from A where date_str > now()`.
[image]

But the index is used when the query condition is another function `right()`.

[image]

Do anyone know why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Store dates in date, datetime, or timestamp fields, not as strings.

Comment: Can you share the query plan? Index may not be used in case of less records or more duplicate values for column date_str.

Comment: I've add the query plain. Thanks @AnilAgrawal

Comment: @Shadow  There is some historical reasons in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query plan, your index will be used if required.

Before applying any index, database query analyzer analyze the query and estimates the cost of different operations.

If query analyzer finds that applying index will improve the query performance then only it will use the index.

These stats changes by increased/decreased/updated data in table.